# How can I transitionally change tempo of some portion of midi drums in Mixcraft 7.0?

Tags: drums, recording

From the last fourth of bridge to chorus and onwards I want tempo to speed up from 100 to 110. How can I do it in my Mixcraft 7.0? what I know is to jump tempo discretely but now I wonder how I can do it continuously so that tempo will increase uniformly between the range I set.

Comment: Check out if your DAW has a thing called "tempo track", and then introduce a continuous change there. Unless you have some very fast notes (64th, etc.) it's enough to change tempo by 1bpm, smaller changes are very hard to notice.

Comment: but I dont want to change tempo after I record a sound at same tempo. its like say a live band is uniformly increasing tempo at some section of song from 105 to 120. I want to reflect that same feeling to the midi drums as the backbone of my song so that I can record every other insturment on top of this "ready" track.. hopefully I am more clear now.

Comment: You should be able to do that, but the details will be DAW-specific.

Comment: This is heavily dependent in which DAW you are using, to get a more specific answer, please tell us which DAW you are arranging with.

Comment: mixcraft 7 pro studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a hardware MIDI controller. Something with a dedicated *tap-tempo* button could be good for ya. They're really common, especially on cheap/entry level equipment. Or you could easily reprogram any generic MIDI button/key/pad to emulate that same behaviour.

Personally though, I'd prefer to map the tempo directly to some kind of linear fader, rotary encoder, etc.. Or better still; a motorized fader.

I don't know what DAW you use though. Some are probably going to be more capable than others, but I can tell you that I've definitely done it before with Avid Protools and Ableton Live. The latter being particularly easy. In fact, if you use Ableton Live, you can even just use the mouse or arrow keys. You could also stretch or warp the actual waveform, but it will sound less natural.

Comment: what about with mixcraft 7? how can I do it with it?

Answer (score 1):

In Mixcraft 7 this is done using markers. Other DAWs have the capability to graph tempo changes, which makes things very easy, but in Mixcraft you need to place a bunch of markers and just change the tempo at each one, so have 10 markers, at 101, 102, 103... up to 110bmp.

Have a look at the [Mixcraft 7 page on Markers](http://www.acoustica.com/mixcraft/v7/help/mixcraft_manual/markers.html) at Acoustica.com - this is the options window for each marker:

[image]

Comment: so how frequent should I put these markers? I should increase or lower tempo only by 1bpm? could you graphicaly show how frequnt it has to be say from 105 to 110?  also mixcraft will release 8th version so maybe they ll offer an easier graphic interface then?  @Dr Mayhem

Comment: also should I put the markers only on midi track in this case drums or on master track? depending on this, will recording other instruments be affected? how? thank you

Comment: You can put them as frequently as you like - I suggested 1bpm increments, as that is not going to be noticed by your listeners.

Comment: Your question about which tracks to use markers on is better served asked as a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Some DAW's will let you insert on the master track a tempo change event.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP knows they can do that. Can you offer an answer on how to do it?